# The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found

Tags: qt, email, outlook

I am new to the Qt framework and I am trying to build my first application using this framework.

The version I am using is Qt SDK 1.2.1 on Windows 7 (using c++).

I am trying to have my application send an email via outlook whenever the user clicks a submit button. I don't require the email to have attachments just want to send an email to a recipient with a predefined message.  The user's requires a company based email.

I am using the following small library to do so [here](https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt/wiki).

I am able to send email via gmail (smtp.gmail.com ,465) and yahoo(smtp.mail.yahoo.com, 465). But cannot do so with outlook emails meaning cannot connect to host. I have tried with my company's email (StartTLS) and get "unknown error".

With the school email  or homtail (smtp.live.com, 587) I get the following message
"The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found"

Not sure what certificate I require.

1) I am wondering if the above library is made for outlook accounts (mainly StartTLS)? Can some one confirm the library works with their outlook account as the SENDER?

2) What may be the issue causing this?

3) If this lib is not made for outlook account what are the alternatives? (looking for something simple in terms of setup and size) Can you provide installation setups on a windows machine.

I have tried libqxt but the process seems cryptic for someone who does know about OpenSSL and Berkeley DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send emails using the user's default email client, I would recommend using something like this:

```
QLabel lblSendEmail = new QLabel();
lblSendEmail.setText("<a href=\"mailto:address@domain.com?Subject=message title here&body=Message body here\">Send Email</a>");
```

Otherwise, I would use an SMTP server to send email like this:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/2221-Sending-email-using-Qt
Modified SMTP class to support SMTP authentication:
https://github.com/nicholassmith/Qt-SMTP

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried sending the email using the user's default email client it does not send anything. Had to change it (a pointer) to so that it may compile. For the STMP thread which post should I start looking at and have you tested it with StartTLS.

Comment: And when use the code in post 3 I get it to compile after commenting out "output" part of the code I get the following error :   Object::connect: No such signal QTcpSocket::error(SocketError) in ..smtp.cpp:9
Object::connect: No such signal QTcpSocket::stateChanged( SocketState) in ..smtp.cpp:11
Object::connect: No such signal QTcpSocket::disconnectedFromHost() in ..smtp.cpp:13
Connected  
connected

Comment: Ok got the company's email working using the following when connected to their network: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/18332-send-mail-from-qt-app-problem      used post number#1 and removed delete sendMail; But it sends the message to the junk mail. How would I add authentication such as password to the smtp code?

Comment: It stop sending to junk mail but still wondering how would I add authentication such as password to the smtp code

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a link to modified code that supports SMTP authentication.

Comment: Seems to work on the my company's network. Will test on a different network to check if it works.  It does not work
with school email but I am not concerned about it(gives 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type if you where wondering). More concerned about indicating the status of the sent email.
Within your code I can easily indicate failure of connection to the host but in-case of invalid user info (wrong password) or unrecognized authentication type is there a way to indicate a failure to user say "your mail was not sent".(would I have to wait till it times out?)

Comment: The class could be extended for different responses from the server. I'm not an expert at the SMTP protocol, but I would try playing around with these commands through a telnet session: http://the-welters.com/professional/smtp.html. It can help you understand the responses that the server sends for various events.

Comment: Thanks for the help Cameron, unfortunately if I am not connected to the company's network I cannot send an email.  I get the following error: Response is:  "504 Unrecognized authentication type".

Comment: You may need to VPN into your company's network or ask your email administrator to look into the authentication problems. Does your company use Microsoft Exchange Server or something else?

Comment: Works with VPN and seems to be good enough (having it connect via another network is not a concern now). I can connect and send emails now, thanks!